# 2 colums: 1 div background image (on scroll beeing cut off), 1 content height: auto;

Tags: html, height, background-image

My mind is glowing of the fact I cannot fix this. I hope someone can help me understand whats happening. I read allot of posts, tried many but seems it's slightly different then my problem.

ingredients:

- 1 body with width + height on 100% and an image pattern on the bg.
- 2 divs for menu left: (1 for a background image and 1 for the menu it self op top of the image)
- 1 div right for the content.

Now, when I use the browser rezise from bottom to the middle and back etc of the screen it's all good. The image still shows it's full size... BUT the moment I use the scrollbar to scroll down the backgroundimage in the menu is beeing cut off.

I use height: 100% and min-height: 100% in all relative objects. I can only think of one thing and that is to use height: 1080px;  but that only usefull when I have more text then the total lenght of the menu bg :(

[Here are the sourcefiles](http://www.webbauer.nl/files.zip)

Comment: did you set body, html { height:100%; } ?

Answer (score 0):

you have two choices either put the menu background in a table a give it a 100% height

or

put the header and content divs inside the menu div, this way the menu div will always be as big as it's content.

```
        <div id="menu_container">
            <div id="menu"></div>
            <div id="header_container"></div>
            <div id="content"></div>
        </div>
```